# Pulling the value from parsed XML in Python (only)

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I am trying to pull a value (only) from some XML in Python using Beautiful Soup (but I'll gleefully dump it for anything else if recommended).  Consider the following bit of code;

```
global humidity, temperature, weatherdescription, winddescription

query = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather="Aberdeen+Scotland"')
weatherxml = query.read()
weathersoup = BeautifulSoup(weatherxml)
query.close()

print weatherxml
```

This prints out the weather forecast for Aberdeen, Scotland as XML (currently) thusly (much XML removed to prevent giant wall of text syndrome);

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><xml_api_reply version="1"><weather module_id="0"
tab_id="0" mobile_row="0" mobile_zipped="1" row="0" section="0"
><forecast_information><city data="Aberdeen, Aberdeen City"/><postal_code data="&quot;Aberdeen Scotland&quot;"/><latitude_e6
data=""/><longitude_e6 data=""/><forecast_date
data="2012-07-31"/><current_date_time data="1970-01-01 00:00:00
+0000"/><unit_system data="US"/></forecast_information><current_conditions><condition
data="Clear"/><temp_f data="55"/><temp_c data="13"/><humidity
data="Humidity: 82%"/><icon
data="/ig/images/weather/sunny.gif"/><wind_condition data="Wind: SE at
8 mph"/></current_conditions>
```

Now I'd like, for example, to be able to populate variables with the values of the weather in this XML, for example make temperature = 13.  Parsing it is proving a nightmare.

If I use any of the find functions on weathersoup, I get the entire tag (e.g for temp_c it returns `"<temp_c data="13">`), various other functions return nothing, or the entire sheet, or parts of it.

How do I simply return the VALUE for any given XML tag, without a mess of "strip"s, or resorting to regex, or basically hacking it?

Comment: you could pass `query` directly to `BeautifulSoup()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access an attribute `data` in element `temp_c`:

```
weathersoup.temp_c['data']
```

Comment: To think the answer was that simple and I spent God knows how long reading the docs and asking on other forums, thanks so much!

Comment: @Elomis: In general `BeautifulSoup` is for html. For xml processing you could use `xml.etree.cElementTree` module from stdlib or `lxml` third-party module: `root = etree.parse(urlopen(url)); data, = root.xpath('//temp_c/@data')`

Answer (score 0):

Use `lxml`, and get friendly with XPath. Some of this example doesn't make sense with the XML you provided, since it doesn't parse correctly... but hopefully it gives you an idea of how powerful XPath can be.

```
from lxml import etree
# xmlstr is the string of the input XML data
root = etree.fromstring(xmlstr)

# print the text in all current_date_time elements
for elem in root.xpath('//current_date_time'):
    print elem.text

# print the values for every data attribute in every temp_c element
for value in root.xpath('//temp_c@data'):
    print value

# print the text for only the temp_c elements whose data element is 'Celsius'
for elem in root.xpath('//temp_c[@data="Celsius"]'):
    print elem.text

# print the text for only the temp_c elements that are under the temperatures element, which is under the root.
for elem in root.xpath('/temperatures/temp_c'):
    print elem.text
```